# Query to get data form different columns

Tags: mysql

I got a problem regarding my query, I cannot seem to get the right one to get the data I want. I've got the following tables I need to get data from:

```
app_exhibition
- id
- name
- form_id

app_forms
- id
- name

app_languages
- id
- name
- code

app_link_lang
- id
- form_id
- lang_id
```

I want to select the name of the exhibition (`app_exhibition`) the id and name of the form (`app_forms`) the name of the language (`app_languages`), and I know which one to select (language wise) because it's linked in the `app_link_lang` table.

Now I got the following query, but that is (obviously) not working..:

```
select f.form_id, f.name, b.name as beursnaam, l.name as languagename 
FROM app_forms f, app_lang_link ll
WHERE f.id=1 
LEFT JOIN app_beurzen b ON (b.form_id = f.id)
LEFT JOIN app_languages l ON ll.form_id = f.id
```

Comment: please provide sqlfiddle

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d3a6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT e.name ename, f.id fid, f.name fname, l.name lname
FROM app_exhibition e
INNER JOIN app_forms f ON f.id=e.form_id
INNER JOIN app_link_lang al ON al.form_id=f.id
INNER JOIN app_languages l ON l.id=al.lang_id
```

You forgot to weave in the link table `app_link_lang` providing the `m-to-n` link. The result can now consist of several lines per exihibition, depending on the languages linked to it in `app_link_lang`.

**Edit**

I extended your fiddle (filled in some data) and it works, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a86be/1

Comment: I get an empty row back... :(

Comment: Try and work your way along by successively replacing some of the `INNER` by `LEFT` in the above query. This should show you, where the desired links did not work for your data. Maybe the keys were not entered correctly? Unfortunately your fiddle does not contain any data. Could you provide a few records?

Comment: Will do, thank you. I filled my fiddle with some data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72825

Comment: Thank you! I got it working with a bit different query: SELECT f.id, f.name, e.name as nameexh, l.name as namelang
FROM app_forms f
LEFT JOIN app_exhbitions e ON f.id = e.form_id
INNER JOIN app_form_link_lang al ON al.form_id = f.id
INNER JOIN app_languages l ON l.id = al.lang_id